# Firebase storage error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

**FirebaseStorage Pod Version (1.0.1)**

```
var storageRef: FIRStorageReference! = FIRStorage.storage().reference()


let uploadTask = storageRef.putData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if (error != nil) {

        } else {
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
            print(downloadURL)
        }
}
```

I simply selected a image from ImagePicker and tried to save Image data to the firebase storage. As illustrated in firebase docs.([Docs Reference)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) **Upload from data in memory** section.

It's throwing following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02025494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03eb2e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01f0c6d2 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 386
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01f2095b +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 75
    4   FirePlay                            0x001e42bc -[FIRStorageUploadTask enqueue] + 815
    5   FirePlay                            0x001e010c -[FIRStorageReference putData:metadata:completion:] + 880
```

The same code used to work before. I am not sure what's the problem now.

Comment: did you `print(image)` ??? .. and verify is it nil or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that we can't put files in root storage node. need to create child node and then only you can save the file. It was clearly [mentioned in the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#create_a_reference) somehow I overlooked it.

E.g

```
let mountainsRef = storageRef.child("mountains.jpg")

let uploadTask = mountainsRef.putData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if (error != nil) {

        } else {
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
            print(downloadURL)
        }
}
```